# array is empty even if it was successfully mapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm running into issues with _.map (using underscore.jshttp://underscorejs.org).

```
getCalories: function() {
  var encode = "1%20";
    var calSource = "https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-data?app_id=#&app_key=#";
    _.map(ingArray, function(elem)
    {
     return $.ajax(calSource, {
      dataType: "json",
      jsonp: "jsonp",
      data: "ingr=" + encode + elem,
      complete: function(r) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
        var calorie = obj.calories;
        calArray.push(calorie);
        console.log(calArray);
      }

    });
  });
},
```

I need to use the latest iteration of calArray in another function. However, it always comes up as undefined. So I inserted a console.log above and this is what I get:

[app.js:177 is the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAuYz.png) 
Is this a scoping issue? Also, if it's logging prior to the push then I can see why it's coming up as undefined. How do I get around it?

Comment: What's the expected outcome of your code? Is it meant to push all results onto an array?

Comment: Yes the results of each Ajax requests (looping with a diff data parameter each time) into a new array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe underscore's `map` produces a new array, in your case the new array will contain a bunch promises (ajax-requests)

You may want to assign this to a variable first, something like below:

```
getCalories: function () {
    var encode = "1%20";
    var calSource = "https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-data?app_id=#&app_key=#";
    var requests = _.map(ingArray, function(elem) {
        return $.ajax(calSource, {
            dataType: "json",
            jsonp: "jsonp",
            data: "ingr=" + encode + elem
        });
    });

    $.when.apply($, requests).then(function(results) {
        console.log(results); // can you take a screenshot of this output
        var calories = _.map(results, function(result) {
            return JSON.parse(result.responseText).calories;
        });
        calArray = calArray.concat(calories);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

I tried it and I received this error:

https://imgur.com/a/WCFWh

Comment: It appears that ```results``` array passed from ```$.when(...).then(...)``` is not a response object, can you share the result you get from ```console.log(results)``` updated code above

Comment: Ah, I think ```$.when``` expects promises as arguments while ```requests``` is an array, I've updated the code